# Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.2.5) x86-mingw32' when running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm trying to learn Ruby on Rails.
Currently been trying out Rails framework. I've installed it. Create new project in MyBlog folder, but when I try to run:

```
rails server
```

I get back an error:

```
Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.2.5) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine. Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I've installed bundle as suggested. Had few problems with installing it as well, but I've found a soultion on the internet.

Before bundle install I was getting another error saying that it could not find gem 'sqlite3'

[image]

Did someone had similar problem? Can you help me with solving it?

Update:

Content of my Gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Errors when try to run 'bundle install':

[image]
[image]

Comment: You had a problem, but solved it with the suggested solution. Great. But you had another problem before? Do you still have it? I cannot follow. What is your actual question? What problem do you face right now?

Comment: @spickermann The problem is not founding rails gem when I run 'rails server' command.

Comment: Can you post your gem file and bundle install errors?

Comment: @SaravanaKumAr Sure, I will edit my post right away.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the following packages to succeed bundle install

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

These packages are for Linux environment. Find the alternatives for other environments. Let me know if you got any error.

Comment: I've tried with gem install build-essentials... But I guess that is not command for Windows that suits the one you provide for Unix.
I got this:

C:\Users\n.mosorinski\Rails\apps\MyBlog>gem install build-essential
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'build-essential' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: knife-essentials, build_eval, essentials, spree_e
ssentials

Comment: I have mentioned that in the answer itself

Comment: Can you check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084811/error-in-installing-json-gem-for-ruby-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

open file Gemfile.lock, find and delete "x64-mingw32" then run the command:-

$bundle install

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but this happened to me just now.
What worked for me was figuring out I accidently installed an older Ruby version.

In your last screenshot you received a line:

`` Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling ``

This command probably failed due to an older Ruby version, get the latest version here (Assuming you're a windows user) https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

P.S

Make sure you remove any previous Ruby / Rails installations.
What you need is a "With DEVKIT" installer, preferably the one they recommend on (starts with "=>").